# Prove/disprove: If $f$ has an anti-derivative in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists and is finite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove/disprove:
>
> 1) If f has an anti-derivative in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists and is finite.
>
> 2) If $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists and is finite, then $f$ has an anti-derivative in [a,b].

Hello everyone, I'm quite baffled with anything that has to do with existence of an anti-derivative. I know that any function that has a removable or jump discontinuity point in some interval I then the function doesn't have an antiderivative at I.
Would be happy to get some help on that question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you heard about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: First one is false, but difficult to show. Look for Volterra function. Second one is also false. Try any function with jump discontinuity

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much! Will read :)

Comment: What does "final" mean here?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I meant "finite".